# Why _printf_l can't print multibyte string of Chinese locale

Tags: unicode

I am using Windows 7, VS2008 to test following code:

```
    wchar_t *pWCBuffer = L"你好，世界"; // some Chinese character

    char    *pMBBuffer = (char *)malloc( BUFFER_SIZE );
    _locale_t locChinese = _create_locale(LC_CTYPE, "chs");

    _wcstombs_l(pMBBuffer, pWCBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE, locChinese ); 
    _printf_l("Multibyte character: %s\n\n", locChinese, pMBBuffer );
```

I convert a wide string to multibyte string and then print it out, using chinese locale, but the printed out string is not right, it is something weird like:  ─π║├ú¼╩└╜τ

How could I print out the right multi-byte string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an absolute answer, because unicode on different platforms can be tricky.  But if your Windows 7 is an English version, then your might want to try the Powershell ISE to see the output.  I use that to print out unicode when writing programs in Ruby too.